# How to block *@domain.com email in Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I am getting spam emails from `xxx@domain.com` where `xxx` is getting changed in every mail. So blocking the sender is not solving the problem. How to blacklist with `*@domain.com` in Gmail?

Comment: We have several similar questions. Please checkout https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgmail%5D+filter+domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many links how to use FILTERS, as Ruben comments.

The steps are

1. In Settings > Filters CREATE a filter
2. just write your actual @domain.com in FROM field of the filter criteria
3. choose DELETE MAIL in the action
   that's it.

You'll love the world of Filters, even more if combined with Labels if you like easy overview of incoming mails.

Answer (score 0):

The subdomains keep changing too, so you should use an * to block the entire domain along with all subdomains, i.e. "*.domain.com"

Comment: The OP's question isn't about changing sub-domains.  Please ask a new question if you have one or have an answer to one.  See the [Tour] as well as [ask] and [answer].  Also note that Gmail search won't differentiate between `from:(*.domain.com)` or `from:(@domain.com)`  or `from:(domain.com)`. They will all return subdomains such as `@subdomain.domain.com`.  The `*` isn't a Gmail search operator nor does the `.` behave as you think.  Gmail search sees both `john.smith` and `john....smith` as `john` beside `smith`